# Is thresholding of image segmentation output required during training

Tags: image-segmentation, loss-function, dice

I am working on image segmentation and I have a problem regarding the loss functions
I am using dice loss as the loss metric.
I found that if the y_pred is not decimal between 0 and 1, the dice coeff seems to have a problem.
To show an example:
lets define dice_coef as follow. And I randomly generate a 2,2,2 tensor with floating points between 0,1
I thought if I input the same tensor to dice_coef, the output should be 1 since both are identical. However it is not the case in the output. Then I try using another tensor with only 0 and 1. The output is 1 as expected.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def dice_coef(y_true,y_pred):
  intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)  #first intersect before reduce_sum
  denominator = tf.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred)
  return (2*intersection)/(denominator)

float_x= np.random.random((2,2,2))
print(float_x)
#[[[0.59969584 0.04508543]
  [0.88194256 0.9227732 ]]

 [[0.37010776 0.95773481]
  [0.04879277 0.47606463]]]
print(dice_coef(float_x,float_x))
# tf.Tensor(0.6299142707152602, shape=(), dtype=float64)

int_x = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 2, 2))
print(dice_coef(int_x,int_x))
# tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

It seems that dice_coef only works in integer 0 and 1 only? So if the output of the segmentation model during training is floating point 0-1, should I be thresholding the value before optimizing using loss function?

Thank you

Comment: when you multiply, things happen that don't happen with intersection, nor do the same things (change in order of magnitude) happen with addition. yes, this might require normalization. if you wanna get creative, throw some logs in there. -- since you DO have a segmentation model, you really should be calculating intersections and unions. IoU is a common metric. it looks like Dice, except the + in the denominator becomes a union (and there's no factor of 2). -- element-wise scalar (non-binary) formulations of intersection and union would be min and max